# SQL to LINQ possible?

Tags: sql, linq

Can this SQL query be translated to LINQ in one select?

```
select ID as SBDID,(select top 1 T.ID from Transactions T where T.SBDID=S.ID order by id desc) as TransID
from SBD S where ID in(223,225)
```

I want to list the last TransactionID for each SBD.ID
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) would help you.

Comment: Very nice @NetMage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have `SBDS` and `TRANSACTIONS`. Every `Sbd` has a primary key `Id`. Every Transaction has a primary key `Id` and a foreign key to the `Sbd` that it belongs to in `SbdId`:

```
class Sbd
{
    public int Id {get; set;}      // Primary key
    ...
}
class Transaction
{
    public int Id {get; set;}      // Primary key
    public int SbdId {get; set;}   // Foreign key to the Sbd that this transaction belongs to
    ...
}
```

Now you want all Sdbs with an Id between 223 and 225, each Sbd with its Transaction with the highest value for Id.

Whenever you see a query for `an object with all or some of its sub-objects`, like a `School with its Students`, a `Bank with his New York Clients`, a `Customer with his Orders`, etc, consider using [GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupJoin__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1____3___)

```
// GroupJoin Sbds and Transactions:
var result = dbContext.Sbds.GroupJoin(dbContext.Transactions, 
    sbd => sbd.Id,                     // from every Sbd, take the Id
    transaction => transaction.SbdId,  // from every Transaction take the SbdId

    // ResultSelector: take the Sbd with all its matching Transactions to make one new:
    (sbd, transactionsOfThisSbd) => new
    {
        Id = sbd.Id,

        // You don't want all transactions of this Sbd, you want only the transaction
        // with the highest Id:
        Transaction = transactionsOfThisSbd
            .OrderByDescending(transaction => transaction.Id)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

Or without all the comment, so you see how small the statement is:

```
    var result = dbContext.Sbds.GroupJoin(dbContext.Transactions, 
    sbd => sbd.Id,
    transaction => transaction.SbdId,
    (sbd, transactionsOfThisSbd) => new
    {
        Id = sbd.Id,
        Transaction = transactionsOfThisSbd
            .OrderByDescending(transaction => transaction.Id)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for the answer and explanations.
This is indeed what I need and it works.

On another note seems it's slower than hitting the db for every **SBD** and getting the latest **Transaction**.

But the same query in SQL runs very quick.

Answer (score 0):

I have not compiled the code but this should work. Context is your dbContext.

```
from s in context.SBD 
select new {
             id = s.id,
             tid = (from t in context.Transactions
                    where t.SBDID == s.id
                    select t).OrderByDescending().First().Id
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: The query ended up like

 `(from s in _context.Sbd
                            select new
                            {
                                id = s.Id,
                                tid = (from t in _context.Transactions
                                       where t.IdSbd == s.Id
                                       select t).OrderByDescending(a => a.IdTransaction).First().IdTransaction
                            }).ToList();`

Comment: Unfortunately it also crashes with:

_{System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , ValueBuffer )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.ProjectionShaper.TypedProjectionShaper`3.Shape(QueryContext queryContext, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at  ...

_